# Program which shows *just* webcam feed?

Tags: webcam

Is there a program I can use which, when launched, does *nothing* but show a stream of my current webcam feed?  `guvcview` does something very similar to this, however when launched it is always accompanied by a huge settings window, which for my purposes I want to eliminate:

[image]

Comment: Yes. cheese shows lots of other settings cruft as well. What I'd like is nothing but a window showing camera feed, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$ ffplay /dev/video0
```